# Running via Spring preloader in process 6426

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spring, twitter-bootstrap, devise

Today I started a new rails project. I integrated devise for authentication and everything went well but when I added bootstrap for styling I got an error or a notice. I got bootstrap up and running with devise and rails but then when I went to add styling to the views generated by typing:

```
rails g devise:views:locale en
```

I got:

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 6426
```

I was supposed to get:

```
create config/locale/devise.views.en.yml
```

I have no idea what went wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Was the file created? It seems that Spring ran the command, and this is the notice you received. It is not an error. It is notifying you that the command you sent was executed by the Spring preloader. Can you make sure the file is not in the locale folder?

Comment: I looked in locale and file is actually there. So now that I know this what do I do from here?

Comment: Spring is used to speed up commands like rake, rails generators, ..., if you don't get an error message, it means your command was successful. Take a look at the GITHUB page, especially in the usage part, you'll see that the output you got is the standard Spring output. https://github.com/rails/spring